# New/delete[] and VirtualAlloc

Tags: c++, memory, new-operator, delete-operator, virtualalloc

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char* pFoo = new unsigned char[1000];

    pFoo = (unsigned char*)VirtualAlloc(NULL, 1000, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    VirtualFree(pFoo, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

    delete[] pFoo;

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

This crashes for me at

```
delete[] pFoo;
```

I know this is crashing because of VirtualAlloc but I'm not sure how to fix this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the same variable. So your first allocation gets leaked.

After you free it with `VirtualFree`, the pointer is invalid. So `delete` on it is undefined.

Furthermore:

You can't mix `VirtualAlloc` and `delete` for the same reason you can't mix `malloc` with `delete`.

Comment: So it just VirtualFree(pFoo, 0, MEM_RELEASE); sufficient?

Comment: Well, the main problem is that you have two different allocations going to the same variable. The second allocation will overwrite the pointer from the first one. Then you try to free/deallocate it twice.

Comment: Could explain what you're trying to accomplish with two allocations? Or perhaps you are misunderstanding something?

Comment: Thanks! I understand, the new isn't needed now.

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned char* pFoo = new unsigned char[1000];
```

Now `pFoo` holds a pointer to dynamic memory.

```
pFoo = (unsigned char*)VirtualAlloc(NULL, 1000, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
```

This overwrites the old pointer, the 1000 `char` array is leaked.

Try:

```
unsigned char* pFoo = new unsigned char[1000];
unsigned char* pBar = (unsigned char*)VirtualAlloc(NULL, 1000, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
VirtualFree(pBar, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
delete[] pFoo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use new/delete or VirtualAlloc/VirtualFree. You are allocating two separate memory blocks, using pFoo to refer to both (when of course it can only refer to one at a time) and then calling the two free functions with pFoo. One of those is going to fail :)